# Selectable folders in fuelux tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview, fuelux

How would you make a 'folder' selectable using a fuelux tree? (i.e each node in the drop down tree is selectable) I've seen an example of this when selecting a folder in google drive:

[image: Google drive - selecting a folder from a tree]

At the moment i'm only able to make 'items' in the tree selectable. Here is an example of tree data that contains folders and items:

```
{"Biology":{
"name":"Biology","type":"folder","classID":1},
"Chemisty":{"name":"Chemisty","type":"folder","classID":2},
"Maths (empty)":{"name":"Maths (empty)","type":"folder","classID":6},
"Jack Woods":{"name":"Jack Woods","type":"item","userID":4},
"Jenny Tran":{"name":"Jenny Tran","type":"item","userID":16}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a feature of the current implementation of the tree.  You can vote for this feature at http://fuelux.uservoice.com/forums/181290-general/suggestions/3745471-is-there-any-way-to-allow-the-selection-of-a-node-

Thanks for the post!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in the meantime i'll look for an alternative. Once i find something ill post a comment. Thanks.